# Microsoft Graph: Are beta APIs bound to the release mode of Office 365?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

We plan to use some specific Microsoft Graph [**beta** APIs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/beta-overview) to access data from Office 365. But our Office 365 tenant will be in **standard** release mode, NOT targeted release.

Is this compatible? Or is the general availability of Microsoft Graph beta/preview APIs somehow bound to the release mode of the tenant the data is being accessed of?

(Of course, when accessing data that can only be created in a targeted release tenant this data won't be available. But will the corresponding (beta) API be callable? Probably returning an error indicating this dicrepancy, or just nothing?)

I want to call beta APIs for standard and targeted release features without having the tenant in targeted release mode. To create a single code base for both release modes.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a correlation between the Microsoft Graph endpoints (`/v1.0` and `/beta`) and your tenant's release mode.

Of course, if you attempt to exercise a method through the API that isn't applicable to your tenant then it will fail. For example, if you attempt to call `/me/messages` but your tenant doesn't have Exchange Online then it wouldn't be able to complete the request.